# When using Typescript, how can I do a return defer.resolve() from my code?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I have coded a function that returns a promise. The function checks to see if there is any configuration data and if there is not then it issues a $http call to get it. Here's the code that I used.

```
   get = (source): ng.IPromise<any> => {
        var self = this;
        var defer = this.$q.defer();
        if (this.loaded == true) {
            return defer.resolve();
        } else {
            this.$http({
                url: '/api/Config/Get',
                method: "GET"
            })
            .success((data: any) => {
               // Some code
            })
            .finally(function () {
                self.loaded = true;
                return defer.resolve();
            })
        }
        return defer.promise;
    }
```

I have a problem with the typescript. It's giving me an error on the return defer.resolve(); line. The error message is:

Error   183 Cannot convert 'void' to 'ng.IPromise'

Can someone tell me how I can return a resolve. It seems return defer.resolve() may not be what I need to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We still have to return the **promise**, so instead of this:

```
if (this.loaded == true) {
    return defer.resolve();
} else {
...
```

we should use

```
if (this.loaded == true) {
    defer.resolve();
    return defer.promise; // here is what MUST be returned, even if resolved already
} else {
...
```

*NOTE:* I'd also change this little part:

```
.finally(function () {
    self.loaded = true;
    return defer.resolve();
})
```

into the arrow function:

```
.finally( () => {
    this.loaded = true;      // this is now what we would expect to be,
    defer.resolve();         // because the 'self' is created by compiler
    return promise;          // also return the promise
})
```